# Push button effect with Imagebutton

Tags: android

I have been working on an app, which basically consists of imagebuttons.

I want to achieve the push button effect with imagebutton.

Is it possible to achieve..

Answer (score 1):

you can programmatically do using `setColorFilter` or `setAlpha` (it depends on the effect you want) to your buttons when you do some action (in this case i suppose onPress).

These are methods inherited from ImageView:

[ImageView Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html)